# Converting a JObject to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using a library developed by another developer in our company. One of the calls in this library returns a JObject. What I need to do is convert this JObject to a dynamic object and return it to my caller.

I've found lots of answers to create a dynamic with NewtonSoft JSON.Net but all the answers use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject which is not applicable in my case as I already have a JsonObject in hand.

Any solutions?

Comment: I guess you could serialize it back to a string and then deserialize it to a dynamic?

Comment: Have you tried simply returning the `JObject`?  When you deserialize into a `dynamic` with Json.Net, it's really a `JObject` under the covers.  `JObject` implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` so it should just work.  No special conversion needed.

Comment: @BrianRogers Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't really understand your problem, but you can convert it like this:

```
dynamic result = yourJobject;
```